# Ставится ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Следует ли ставить запятую в предложении "Мы поддерживаем iOS и Android и Windows Phone". Вроде бы тут схема такая: O и O и O. Что можете сказать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь нужно понимать смысл слов, написанных по-английски. Давайте лучше на русском материале. На полянке растут колокольчики, и ромашки, и васильки. Однородные подлежащие связаны повторяющимся союзом И, запятая ставится после каждого однородного члена. На полянке растут грибы и колокольчики и ромашки. Здесь запятые не нужны. Колокольчики и ромашки - пара однородных членов, близких по смыслу. Первый союз И соединяет в качестве однородных слово и пару слов. Запятые не нужны. Смотрите сами, какой вариант подходит в вашем случае.

Answer (score 1):

В Интернете можно прочитать: "iOS, Android и Windows Phone - именно эти три мобильные ОС являются доминирующими на рынке, и поэтому данное противостояние интересно вдвойне". "Смарт-браслет получит поддержку Windows Phone, Android и iOS".

В этих сообщениях системы не противопоставляются друг другу, поэтому можно предположить, что схема такая: O, и O, и O: "Мы поддерживаем iOS, и Android, и Windows Phone".

Но коммуникативно предложение не очень удачно составлено. В любом случае, принцип расстановки союзов не кажется ясным.

Comment: А правилен ли он по правилам? :)

Comment: Можно записать: "Мы поддерживаем iOS и Android и Windows Phone", но при этом вы по каким-то причинам противопоставляете группу "iOS и Android"  и Windows Phone. Первый союз И связывает две системы, а второй союз И соединяет эту группу с третьей системой.

Comment: А. Конечно, самое популярное написание следующее: "iOS, Android и Windows Phone", как мне кажется.

Comment: Да, и в этом случае мы считаем эти системы равноправными.